# Вывод данных из таблицы [MySQL]

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет, есть таблица которая содержит данные записей:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И еще таблица которая содержит данные какой пользователь подписан на кого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть переменная `$authedUser` со значением `1` ( `ID` авторизованного пользователя)

Я пытаюсь вывести все записи с первой таблицы, автором которого является авторизованный пользователь и все остальные записи пользователей которые есть в подписках этого пользователя:

```
SELECT tb1.*, tb2.* 
FROM `posts` tb1, `follows` tb2 
WHERE (tb2.user_id = '{$authedUser}' 
          AND tb2.with_user_id = tb1.id_post_author
      ) 
      OR tb1.id_post_author = '{$authedUser}' 
ORDER by tb1.date DESC
```

Выводятся записи пользователей которые есть в подписках, но записи автором котого является авторизованный пользователь дублируются несколько раз! В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: *В чем может быть проблема?* В отсутствии DISTINCT.

Comment: казалось бы запрос на `union`

Comment: @Akina, не помогло, либо я не правильно сделал ‍♂️  Можно подробнее?

Comment: @teran можно подробней? я плохо разбираюсь в mysql

Answer (score 0):

> Я пытаюсь вывести все записи с первой таблицы, автором которого является авторизованный пользователь

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, ....
FROM posts AS p 
WHERE p.id_post_author = ?
```

> и

```
UNION
```

> все остальные записи пользователей которые есть в подписках этого пользователя:

```
SELECT p.id, ...
FROM posts AS p
INNER JOIN follows AS f ON (
      p.id_post_author = f.with_user_id
      AND f.user_id = ?
   )
```

для сортировки убираем это все в "подзапрос", и сортируем

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    select ...
    union
    select
) AS p
ORDER BY p.date
```

либо же в ваш запрос добавить `DISTINCT`: `SELECT distinct p.id, p.title ...`